# my application not resume when reopen?

Tags: android, resume

My application is not resuming to previous state when it is reopen 
Although its working well when a call is recieved or other application is open and then closed it comes in front

but

> **when HOME_KEY is pressed it start from first activity.**
>
> **It not happened on Emulator it Happens only on device**

It happens from any activity among many activities in my app

Comment: check if you have android:launchMode="singleTask" in your launch activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you reimplement the `onResume()` method in your activity?

I'm not sure what state you need to restore, but perhaps [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) might help (duplicate?)?

You are familiar with the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)?

Comment: yes i've done and so that when phone call recieved and other app is come in front it resume back to current activity the problem is with only when home button is clicked and also it not in emulator it happen on device MOTO only

Comment: Sounds like a device/model specific problem. Could it be that your device runs garbage collection on that activity? As you might be aware, pausing an app does not guarantee it will be resumed; memory might be needed elsewhere during the app's paused state and therefore GCed. Perhaps you run some background service app, like a network, memory or battery saver, which automatically kills processes?

Comment: i'm sure my app process is not killed and also i found that every time my main activity is started not the new session all the previous session is just fill the stack on one another

Comment: Try uninstalling the app on your device, and then reinstall it again.